# Should I get paid breaks and if so, how long?

Tags: hours, break-time, australia

My job states I have to do 38 hours a week, I can come in, work and then leave whenever I want (between certain hours). I have to log my hours into a timesheet website and we can get as long as we like for breaks whenever we want also.

I'm wondering how I should log my time, obviously if I take an hour and a half break for lunch I'm not going to log all that time. But surely there is some break time that should be paid, and some that is unpaid and should work for longer.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on your organisation's policies.  Voting to close.

Comment: The contract does not say anything about breaks though, isn't it a legal requirement to give paid breaks?

Comment: I have no idea :)  You haven't stated what country or industry you are in.  But it sounds remarkably like you should be talking to the HR department in your organisation instead of random people on the internet :)

Comment: Australia and IT (programming), probably, but I'm very shy haha, plus I've been here for like 5 months so at this point I'm too afraid to ask.

Comment: Ok, I am in IT and in Australia and it is very dependent on the organisation.  Talk to HR.  Time to overcome your shyness ;)

Comment: `obviously if I take an hour and a half break for lunch I'm not going to log all that time` - why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to try to answer this as I work in the same country and same industry.

If you take an hour and a half for lunch, you record your start and finish time.  You are being paid to work 38 hours a week.  You need to make sure that you accurately record your time in your timesheet and that it adds up to 38 hours. You are not entitled to be paid for long lunches.

This means that if you take an hour and a half lunch, you need to either start earlier or go home later to make up the extra break time.  As far as I am aware in Australia, there are *no* paid breaks like this.  You need to work your hours around your time away to add up to your contracted hours.

Comment: not even part of lunch, like the first 20mins?

Comment: No, why should they?  You are asked to work 38 hours.  You can take lunch breaks.  If you take an hour and a half lunch break, you need to work your 7.6 hours a day on either side of that.  I have _never_ heard of you being paid for this in IT.  It's not McDonalds ;)

Comment: Okay, yeh this is my first full time job. I've been basing my knowledge off my casual job experience, which I know they have to give you paid breaks if you work 4+ hours. Thanks

Comment: I gathered that was the case when you mentioned the 20 minutes part ;)  Good luck!